# How do you get the Apple Watch out of Power Reserve mode?

Tags: power, apple-watch

I got it into power reserve but can't figure how to resume normal mode. I have tried tapping and pressing the screen and holding both side buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can bring your Apple Watch back to normal functioning mode by pressing and holding the side button, the same way that you do when you wish to power it on.

This command will only work if you plugged the Watch in, or if there is sufficient battery juice available.

Answer (score 3):

You can hold the Digital Crown and Side Button at the same time for 6 seconds and then wait until it shuts down and turn it back on. This is force shutting it down and won't damage or effect your watch.

Comment: Up voted for saying how long you need to hold it down for and also for explaining that its actually shutting it down and not just toggling the power reserve mode.

Answer (score 0):

FYI
I charged my watch to 100% and then put it in power reserve.
I couldn't get it to come out no matter what.
Then I saw the comment about pressing both side "devices" (button and rocker switch).
Was the only way to get t to come out of power reserve.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold the *digital crown* and the *side button* for 5 seconds or so.
That should work if your Apple Watch is charging.

Comment: How is this different from the earlier answer above?