# Can't take Apple Watch out of power saving mode

Tags: apple-watch, power-management

I still can’t get my Apple Watch Series 3 out of power saving mode and I have held down the side buttons, and held down both buttons for at least 6 seconds. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seek repair if your device doesn’t charge or operate normally.

- [How do you get the Apple Watch out of Power Reserve mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184644/how-do-you-get-the-apple-watch-out-of-power-reserve-mode)
- [Why does my Apple Watch keep entering Power Reserve mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256951/why-does-my-apple-watch-keep-entering-power-reserve-mode)